# Arduino MLX90614 to Pyserial error converting String to Float

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

Good Day! I was struggling about my arduino MLX90614 code my pyserial cant read the data it show's

Here's my arduino MLX90614 code:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_MLX90614.h>
Adafruit_MLX90614 mlx = Adafruit_MLX90614();

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); 
  mlx.begin();  
}

void loop() {
  Serial.print("Ambient = "); Serial.print(mlx.readAmbientTempC()); 
  Serial.print("*C\tObject = "); Serial.print(mlx.readObjectTempC()); Serial.println("*C");
  Serial.print("Ambient = "); Serial.print(mlx.readAmbientTempF()); 
  Serial.print("*F\tObject = "); Serial.print(mlx.readObjectTempF()); Serial.println("*F");
  Serial.println();
  delay(500);
}
```

And heres my python code "Pyserial" to read the data from my arduino

```
import csv
from time import time

import serial

# Your serial port might be different!
ser = serial.Serial('COM5', timeout=1)

f = open("df.csv", "a+")
writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')

while True:
    s = ser.readline().decode()
    if s != "":
        rows = [float(x) for x in s.split(',')]
        # Insert local time to list's first position
        rows.insert(0, int(time()))
        print(rows)
        writer.writerow(rows)
        f.flush()
```

But in result it show's this

"rows = [float(x) for x in s.split(',')]
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Ambient 30c /n'"

Someone please help me with this I am really struggling with connecting my Arduino MLX90614 to my Arduino. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you considered simply *not printing* "Adafruit MLX90614 test" in your Arduino code?  You either need to do that, or recognize that line on the Python side and refrain from calling `float()` on it.

Comment: So how coult it fix it? Please I am truly beginner that creating thesis project  now it shows

 rows = [float(x) for x in s.split(',')]
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Ambient = 38.33*C\tObject = 33.19*C\r\n'

@jasonharper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If s != '' is not a space, add the whitespace between the quotes, this is returning values that cannot be passed to the int constructor.

Comment the list comprehension out and print instead to see the current values your code is storing.